# How to center widget in Custom Scroll View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a custom scroll view in which I want to center the widget as per the API and take a full vertical space . I am only able to center horizontally.

```
Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    slivers: [
                      SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                          [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20.h,
                            ),
                            Stack(children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("test");
                                  Get.toNamed(home);
                                },
                                child: RotatedBox(
                                  quarterTurns: 3,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Projects",
                                    style: themeData.textTheme.headline1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const CustomAboutWidget() // center this vertically 
                            ],),
                          ],
```

Entire code tree on paste code

https://pastecode.io/s/k02esc95

Comment: is parent `Expanded` is main body?

Comment: This code-snippet through bunch of errors, can you simplify and include the reproducible code-snippet

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/k02esc95 check out the link for remaining code tree  @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Can you update the question including  more details and with rest code

Comment: nope as the StackOverflow is throwing the error with the question with the entire code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SliverFillRemaining` widget inside your `CustomScrollView` and set its property `hasScrollBody` to a false value.

Please find a snip code below as an example.

```
SliverFillRemaining(
  hasScrollBody: false,
  child: Container(
    child: CustomText(
      text: "Some Dummy Text",
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  ),
)
```